# Why isn't it possible to declare multiple method prototypes per line?

Tags: objective-c, c, methods, syntax, prototype

Given that…

```
@interface Hog : NSObject { NSUInteger one, two, three;      }
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *four, *five, *six;
-(void) seven;
@end
@implementation Hog
static CGFloat f, ff, fff;
- (NSString*) six { return _four = _five = _six  =  @"sexy"; }
- (void) seven    {          one =   two = three =       33;
                               f =    ff =   fff =     6.66;
                         SEL sevenSelect = @selector(seven);
   NSLog(@" %ld, %0.2f, %@, %@",
   three, fff, self.six, NSStringFromSelector(sevenSelect)); }
@end
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){ Hog *u = Hog.new; [u seven];}

Output: 33, 6.66, sexy, seven
```

**Then.. why isn't it possible then, to declare**

`-(void)seven, eight, nine;`

in the header, etc?  What's the difference? Doesn't `objc-c` just treat the `IMP`, *or whatever it is*, the same way as any other variable, block, etc?  Why even bother with the prototype, anyways?  Especially, why bother if it is in a class extension, and you're just going to write method directly underneath.  It seems like just another opportunity for mistakes, and needless repetition, no?  I know I'm wrong, but I'm asking to be schooled, so go ahead.

Comment: Because it isn't. It's a language (C). It works the way it works. — Of course in modern Objective-C you don't need to declare methods anyway (unless you are making them public in the .h file).

Comment: That would be pretty ambiguous for prototypes like `- (id)initWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Method declarations are not the same thing, syntactically, as variable declarations. They have a different syntax and can only occur in specific contexts.

Would it be possible to modify Objective-C's syntax to allow multiple variable declarations separated by commas? Yes, it would — but it would require bigger changes than you're envisioning, as declarations can get a lot more complex when they include arguments. And there's little point in making a major syntactic change just to allow people to write less readable declarations. There is literally zero benefit to that.